# Script to add Change Format Functionality to "Find and Replace" Feature

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

New to scripts for Google Docs, and currently looking for an existing script to add change format functionality to "Find and Replace" feature. For example Selecting Column B, finding every instance of a word, using "Find and replace", and instead of only being able to replace the word, having the functionality to change the format to bold or italics.

I've searched and haven't been able to find anything myself, so if anyone knows of a script, it would be greatly appreciated.

If not, can someone please give me a hint of where to start, in regards to creating this script myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to find and replace text in Google Docs, however it will need modifying if you want to change the *formatting* of found text.

```
function replaceInSheet(sheet, to_replace, replace_with) {
  //get the current data range values as an array
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  //loop over the rows in the array
  for(var row in values){

    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value){
      return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
    });

    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    values[row] = replaced_values;
  }

  //write the updated values to the sheet
  sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
}
```